# How do you identify authentcated user in WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a WCF service that will be using basic authentication and would like to be able identify "who" is trying to use the service.  I know that the HttpContext.Current is NULL and in the WCF service, but do not know what the alternative is to get the username.

#### For the website, I can use:

```
userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

#### How do I get userName in the WCF Service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
string login = OperationContext.Current
                               .ServiceSecurityContext
                               .PrimaryIdentity
                               .Name;
```

Obviously it helps to check for null reference exceptions along that path but you get the idea.

Comment: Watch out - the PrimaryIdentity could be NULL! Just make sure to check for that....

Answer (score 2):

OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name